# Why does console.log behave different from .innerText/.innerHTML properties

Tags: javascript

I wanted to write an answer with the following code to another, but `console.log` behaves different from `.innerText`/`.innerHTML` properties. Why? How can I get the outputs of `console.log` onto screen instead of console?

HTML,

```
<button type="button" id="click">Click <strong>me</strong></button>
```

Javascript,

```
const ll = document.querySelector(`#click`);
const tt = document.createElement(`div`);
const t = document.createElement(`p`);
ll.addEventListener(`click`, function (event) {
  t.innerText += event;
  t.innerText += event.target;
  t.innerText += event.currentTarget;
  tt.appendChild(t);
  document.body.appendChild(tt);
  console.log(event);
  console.log(event.target);
  console.log(event.currentTarget);
});
```

**`Edit:`** I get same result by using `.innerHTML`

[image]

Comment: Assigning to `innerText` will always convert the assigned value to string. This doesn't happen when you do `console.log`.

Comment: `t.innerText += event.target` converts `event.target` object to string and it's `[object Object]` as string. Try `innerHtml`

Comment: @Justinas nothing changes with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning to `.innerText` will always convert the assigned value to string. This doesn't happen when you do `console.log`

The `console` API renders values according to their type. Notably, objects are represented in some interactive (collapse/expand) way, using specific font styling (colors, italics, ...) to give more hints to the user. Furthermore, `console` shows properties which are not necessarily own properties, or enumerable. To reproduce this yourself will require quite some coding.

You can get a long way with a function that creates a JSON representation of properties (including inherited ones) that are primitive values and not null and where the property names are not all CAPS (which usually represent constants).

Also, display in a DOM element that retains line breaks (white-space is pre):

```js
function objectString(obj) {
  let result = {}
  for (let prop in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[prop] !== "function" && typeof obj[prop] !== "object" && prop.toUpperCase() !== prop) {
      result[prop] = obj[prop];
    }
  }
  return obj.constructor.name + ":\n" 
      + JSON.stringify(result, null, 2) + "\n";
}

const ll = document.querySelector(`#click`);
const tt = document.createElement(`div`);
const t = document.createElement(`pre`);
ll.addEventListener(`click`, function(event) {
  t.innerText = objectString(event) +
    objectString(event.target) +
    objectString(event.currentTarget);
  tt.appendChild(t);
  document.body.appendChild(tt);
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="click">Click <strong>me</strong></button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but if you can see from the console output, I want to show the diff between `target` and `currentTarget`. I want to get the results on DOM instead of console. The properties and values printed and shown by `objectString` on DOM doesn't tell us that.

Comment: I don't understand what you want different then. The output produced in my answer is clearly different for `target` and `currentTarget`. For instance when you click on "me", the  `nodeName` property has different values ("BUTTON" versus "STRONG"). And yes, this output is in the DOM. So I don't understand why you write "I want to get the results on DOM instead of console", because that is exactly what my answer is doing.

Comment: To highlight the difference more, you could prefix the return value with `obj.constructor.name + ":\n" + `. I have updated my answer like that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the properties you want from the mouseevent.

Your console log is logging event.target, the name of the button clicked.

Your console has all the event properties, including screenX, screenY, etc. If it's these you want, change event.target to, for example, event.screenX

A list of available properties to these events is at:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_mouseevent.asp

You could also research differences between innerText, innerHTML and textContent